# Graph ending in mathbox.js

Tags: javascript, graph

I'm trying to learn some mathbox.js basics, let's say the domumentation is not the worst, but it lacks a lot of info. Now, my problem is this:

I'm trying to draw a circle in a cartesian view, so I wrote:

```
 var data =
  view.interval({
  expr: function (emit, x, i, t) {
    emit(x, Math.sqrt(4 - (x*x)));
    emit(x, -Math.sqrt(4 - (x*x)));

  },
  length: 1024,
  channels: 2,
  items: 2,
});

var curve =
view.line({
width: 4,
color: '#3090FF',
  zIndex: 2,
  });
```

But it gives me this:

[image]

I have no idea why, I have tried setting all the possible parameters of the line, but it keeps the same(or disappears)

What can I do so the end of the lines merge?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect mathbox does have some way to connect two line segments, but I don't know it.

One other solution to this problem would be to draw the circle using a different parametrization, e.g., `(R*cos(t),R*sin(t))`. Two advantages to this parameterization:

1. Draw circle as a single curve, rather than two curves (that would need to be connected)
2. Sample points will be equally spaced in angle (rather than equally spaced in `x`).

Here's the code:

```
var data =
    view.interval({
        range: [-π, π],
        expr: function (emit, theta, i, t) {
            R = 2;
            x = R*Math.cos(theta);
            y = R*Math.sin(theta);
            emit(x, y);
        },
        width: 64,
        channels: 2,
    });

var curve =
    view.line({
        width: 5,
        color: '#3090FF',
    });
```